# In a TCL script how do I echo the content of a variable?

Tags: tcl, vhdl, modelsim, quartus

I am writing a TCL script for modelsim, and I want to compare the output value of a signal to a constant to know the circuit is working correctly. I know how to control the input signals but can't figure out how to echo the output.

Ideally I'd be able to pipe everything to a csv file, but it'd be enough to have the script return a pass/fail.

Still I need to read the value of an output (in my case it's sim:/union/outf) in a similar way to something like [$echo outf] on bash

PS. I realize the title may be misleading, because I can print the value of a variable declared inside the script. I need to print the current value of a wave output.

[image: I'd want to save each value of 'outf' to later compare it]

Comment: I would suggest that you're much better to generate stimulus and check outputs by writing VHDL (or some other HDL) rather than trying to do it with TCL. It's easier, much more powerful, not proprietary and what the whole industry does.

Answer (score 2):

When using Modelsim, the TCL command to echo the output is to use "examine"

```
examine -hex /tb/my_signal
```

Answer (score 0):

The *direct* equivalent in Tcl of bash's `echo $out` is:

```
puts $out
```

Or, if the variable is an environment variable:

```
puts $env(out)
```

Comment: Whether that is the right thing for your application… well, that's a different matter entirely.

Comment: It is not right for modelsim ;) he's talking about a different kind of variable..